# how to extract form tag using htmlagility pack?

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I'm using `HtmlAgilityPack` in one of my `C#` Projects for scraping. I need to scrap the `<form>` tag from web page. I've searched about how to extract form tag using HtmlAgilityPack but couldn't find an answer. Can anyone tell me how to extract `<form>` tag using `HtmlAgilityPack`?

```
private void Testing()
        {
            var getHtmlWeb = new HtmlWeb();
            var document = getHtmlWeb.Load(@"http://localhost/final_project/index.php");
            HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");
            var aTags = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form");
            int counter = 1;
            StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
            if (aTags != null)
            {
                foreach (var aTag in aTags)
                {
                    buffer.Append(counter + ". " + aTag.InnerHtml + " - " + "\t" + "<br />");
                    counter++;
                }
            }
        }
```

Here is my code sample. I'm scraping a page from my `localhost`. count of `aTags` is 1 because there is only one form on page. But when I use but my `StringBuilder` object doesn't contain any InnerHtml of form. Where's is the error :(

Here is my html source from which I want to scrap `form`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- stylesheet section -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="./_include/style.css">

    <!-- title of the page -->
    <title>Login</title>

    <!-- PHP Section -->
    <!-- Creating a connection with database-->
     <!-- end of PHP Sectoin -->

    </head>
        <body>
            <!-- now we'll check error variable to print warning -->
                        <!-- we'll submit the data to the same page to avoid excessive pages -->
            <form action="/final_project/index.php" method="post">
                <!-- ============================== Fieldset 1 ============================== -->
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Log in credentials:</legend>
                    <hr class="hrzntlrow" />
                        <label for="input-one"><strong>User Name:</strong></label><br />
                        <input autofocus name="userName" type="text" size="20" id="input-one" class="text" placeholder="User Name" required /><br />

                        <label for="input-two"><strong>Password:</strong></label><br />
                        <input name="password" type="password" size="20" id="input-two" class="text" placeholder="Password" required />
                </fieldset>
                <!-- ============================== Fieldset 1 end ============================== -->

                <p><input type="submit" alt="SUBMIT" name="submit" value="SUBMIT" class="submit-text" /></p>
            </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since form tags are allowed to overlap , HAP handles them differently, to treat form tags as any other element just remove the form flag by calling:

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");
```

Now your form tags will be handled as you expect, and you can work with the way you work with other tags.

Comment: I've posted my code sample. Can you please check it?

Comment: @ZohaibAslam you need to remove the flag before you load the document, so just shift the remove flag up 2 lines